# How to handle Korean character set between QT & Oracle

Tags: c++, oracle, qt, unicode

I'd like to use Oracle with ODBC.

I could get data from Oracle successfully. But Korean character is broken like ????.
As all programmer said on internet forum, I tried to apply `QTextCodec` like below.

I tried `EUC-KR` and other codec names. But no change.

```
   QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8");
   QSqlQuery q("select * from temp", db);
             q.setForwardOnly(true);
           QString contect= "";
           while(q.next())
           {
               QByteArray name = q.value(0).toByteArray();
               QString age = q.value(1).toString();
               contect = contect +  codec->toUnicode(name);

               ui.textEdit->setText(contect);
           }
```

Oracle side info is.....

```
NLS_CHARACTERSET : KO16MSWIN949 
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET : AL16UTF16
NLS_LANG : KOREAN_KOREA.KO16MSWIN949
```

I'm developing with eclipse (on windows 7) and the default file text encoding is utf-8.

I'll appreciate it if you give me comment.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you create another `QTextCodec *codec2 = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-16");1 for UTF-16?` and then do a `contect = contect +codec2->toUnicode(name);` ?

Comment: ¤ Perhaps it would help to translate from the character encoding of the DB result, to the encoding used by QT strings. Your incorrect results do indicate strongly that that's not what you're currently doing. I.e., that the DB result is not UTF-8 encoded. Cheers & hth,

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the codec name as you need a codec from the Korean character set *into* UTF8.

Try changing your code to:

```
QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("cp949");
```

As the Wikipedia page for [Code page 949](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_949) mentions that it is non-standard Microsoft version of EUC-KR, you could also try `EUC-KR`.

Try the following program to get the list of text codecs and aliases:

**test.cpp**

```
#include <QtCore>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
        const auto codecs = QTextCodec::availableCodecs();
        for (auto it = codecs.begin(); it != codecs.end(); ++it)
        {
                const auto codec = QTextCodec::codecForName(*it);
                qDebug() << codec->name() << codec->aliases();
        }
        return 0;
}
```

**test.pro**

```
QT += core
SOURCES=test.cpp
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x
```

Note that the program uses `auto` for brevity, but this requires a C++11 compiler (tested on GCC 4.4).